# GAN loss suddenly explodes and model breaks

Tags: deep-learning, gan

Almost every time I've tried to train a DCGAN using keras I find that the loss suddenly skyrockets and the model completely stops improving. I find this happens regardless of what combination of loss functions, learning rates, label smoothing, or any other "GAN hack" I employ (and I've tried a lot, including cloning and running other people's models). Here is my most recent example, from a DCGAN that uses linear activation and MSE loss (metrics are D loss, D accuracy, G loss, G accuracy):

```
Epoch 26: 04224/04334; D=0.147 (79.7%); G=0.646 (14.4%);
Epoch 27: 04224/04334; D=0.139 (80.6%); G=0.644 (15.2%);
Epoch 28: 04224/04334; D=0.151 (79.0%); G=0.646 (14.2%);
Epoch 29: 04224/04334; D=199583.580 (75.8%); G=328619.291 (18.6%);
Epoch 30: 04224/04334; D=262175.355 (31.6%); G=14210.427 (77.9%);
Epoch 31: 04224/04334; D=948.686 (49.5%); G=135.858 (46.9%);
```

Here are the corresponding image aggregates:
[image]

I understand that GANs typically fail to converge, but haven't been able to find anyone else with this specific issue (massive model-breaking spike). Any idea what could be causing it?

Comment: The information provided in the question is probably not enough to give a sensible answer. The cause of the problem could be an implementation error, an incorrect choice of hyperparameters or many other things. Please consider adding more information or a minimum working example of your problem to improve our prospects for finding an answer.

Comment: Thanks for your time @ncasas. [Here's the gist of it](https://gist.github.com/ConorLazarou/1aabd8eadf472524c542989a9d0c641e), it's pretty basic. Note that I'm not exaggerating when I say _every_ technique I've tried does this, including (upscale+conv, transposed conv, pixel shuffle), (uniform noise, gaussian noise), (mixed classes, pure classes), (hard labels, smooth classes), (sigmoid+binary_crossentropy, linear+MSE). I'm starting to think that maybe there's an overflow issue or defect with my GPU.